# How to specify page size in dynamically in yii view?

Tags: yii

How to specify **page size** in dynamically in yii view?(not a grid view)
In my custom view page there is a search option to find list of users between 2 date
i need 2 know how to specify the page size dynamically? If number of rows less than 10 how to hide [pagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination) ?[image]

please check screen-shoot

**I dont want the page navigation after search it confusing users..**

my controller code

```
            $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
        $count=CustomerPayments::model()->count($criteria);
        $pages=new CPagination($count);
        // results per page
        $pages->pageSize=10;
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);
        $paymnt_details=CustomerPayments::model()->findAll($criteria);
   $this->render('renewal',array('paymnt_details'=>$paymnt_details,'report'=>$report,'branch'=>$branch,'model'=>$model,'pages' => $pages,));    
    }
```

my view
[Link](http://pastebin.com/mpR3uWA3)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the entire list of search result be shown on a single page, no-matter how long it is?

If so, this is quite easy to achive.

As I can see in your code, you are now defining your pageSize to have a size of 10. You can update it to be dynamically be doing this:

```
$pages->pageSize = $count;
```

To remove the pagesizes you can change the css of your view file, but for that we would need your view file to see how you defined it.

Comment: I want entire list of search result be shown on a single page but before searching shows in multiple page.Assume that search result is a single page